# How to prepare my data for a Neural Network training for a natural gas ( NATGAS ) price-predictions?

Tags: networking, machine-learning, neural-network, trading

I want to create an NN to predict future prices in natural gas

I'm not sure it's a simple time series problem:

Each month ( so 12 of these) I follow a future spread ( e.g sep-oct ) until the front contract expires.

I start following it for approx 60 days ( data points ).

For each of the data points I have other inputs e.g. weather, inventories for the week, price of coal etc.

I have the previous 5 yrs data for each spread for each of the months of the year.

I want the NN to learn if it can predict the direction of the current months spread for the next x days of the 60 days for the particular months spread, given that I'll know weather, inventories, coal prices etc. -- the Features Vector -- at the moment of prediction.

Qus's I'd like to know if it can predict -"given this years inventories, weather patterns, coal price - where will the spread go in the next last 20 days of the contract?"

**Is this suitable for a NN-based Predictor**?

If so **how should I be preparing my data?**

I'm using MATLAB

Comment: If you want please contact with me, we can cooperate in the filed that problem.

Comment: Hi - tks for your offer... let me know when free to discuss further?

Comment: Click on my profile..

Comment: @user2875015 Have you got any closer to an answer to your Task?